# Clear timer using clearInterval is not working

Tags: javascript, timer

I put my work online here :

how to reproduce :

- Click on a green pin on the map to choose a station
- Fill the two inputs name / lastname
- Sign the canvas
- You should see a timer starting 20:00 min
- If you cancel (annule button) the timer
- Then resign the canvas, the timer is still going, its not reset

My timer is in the file /js/timer.js
I don't understand why, because I clearInterval my `this.setTimer` when I call the button line 59, I used `timer.cancel` method to clearInterval and clear the sessionStorage.
But I tried to debug and weird things, `this.setTimer` appears to be equal to 10, then each time I cancel, `this.setTimer` increases by  1.

Did I miss something ? The proper behavior should be when I click on "annule" (cancel) the timer reset to 20:00 min

Here my cancel function

```
cancel = () => {
    this.isPlaying = false;
    clearInterval(this.setTimer);
    sessionStorage.clear();
    console.log(this.setTimer);
    canvas.clear();
    this.timer.innerHTML = 'Votre réservation a été annulée.'
    document.getElementById('reservation-content').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.getElementById('cancel-btn').className = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('validation-btn').setAttribute('disabled', null)
}
```

Comment: show how do you try to clear timer, example is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.delta
```

stores old value when you subtracted 1000.

after clear interval you need to reset `this.delta` value again.
Try adding

```
this.delta = (this.endDate - this.now);
```

after

```
clearInterval(this.setTimer);
```

in cancel method.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thanks perfect I totally forgot about it !